# Using variable as end point of loop - C#

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am calculating month's days based on *cmbYear* & *cmbMonth* with the below code:

```
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt16(cmbYear.SelectedItem), Convert.ToDateTime("01-" + cmbMonth.SelectedItem + "-2011").Month);
```

What I am trying to achieve, using *for loop*, is to create a drop down list that includes all numbers starting from **1** to `int days` for `cmbDay` combo box. Below is my code which generates an error when I am trying to import the end point of the code `i = days;`. Error in *Cannot implicitly convert type int to bool*.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
for (int i = 1; i = days; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: The middle part is supposed to be a condition which determines how the loop is run. Now it's an assignment `i = days`, which cannot be converted to a boolean result. You probably mean `i < days` or `i <= days`

Comment: Typo? `i = days;` means "**assign** `days` to `i`"

Comment: The for statement seems odd comparison should be ==. As previous people mentioned it should probably be something like <= or <

Comment: I am sure you would be able to solve your problem now or should I post an answer too ? :D

Comment: Apart from what everyone else has suggested for the *Invalid Condition Syntax*, as an alternative to the `Loop`, you could use something like this:`var daysAr = Enumerable.Range(1, days).ToArray();`. to generate an array of number of days in a month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the Loop should Looks like

```
for (int i=1; i <= days; i++)
```

or

```
for (int i=1; i < days; i++)
```

depends on what you Need.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `<=` instead of `=`

```
for (int i=1; i <= days; i++)
{

}
```

The second parameter is the condition. As long as it is true, the loop goes on

Answer (score 1):

[for (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for)

> The for statement defines initializer, condition, and iterator
>   sections:
>
> ```
> for (initializer; condition; iterator)
>     body
> ```
>
> **The condition section**
>
> **The condition section, if present, must be a boolean expression**. That
>   expression is evaluated before every loop iteration. If the condition
>   section is not present or the boolean expression evaluates to true,
>   the next loop iteration is executed; otherwise, the loop is exited.

You had `i = days` which is an assignment, and results in an `int` which is not a condition (`bool`).. What you probably intended was  `i == days` which is still wrong.

What you needed was the following, which says *"while `i` is less then `days`, loop the body"*

```
for (int i=1; i < days; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple syntactical error. you've misses an '<'

```
for(int i=1; i<=days;i++){..}
```